# MySQL Key column 'product_id' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to follow this video for class but I'm getting an error but I don't see where it is in the video and I'm too new to using the command prompt and MySQL to see it.

this is the error " at line 49: Key column 'product_id' doesn't exist in table"

this is the video incase that's needed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ec--JuXWVu4

this is the code

```
create database if not exists customers;

use customers;

drop table if exists phonenumbers;
drop table if exists product_orders;
drop table if exists products;
drop table if exists orders;
drop table if exists customers;

CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    street varchar(25),
    state char(2) NOT NULL,
    zip char(5),
    city varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE phonenumbers (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    customer_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    phone_number varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) references customers(id)
);

create table orders (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    customer_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    date_ordered datetime default current_timestamp,
    date_delivered datetime,
    total decimal(7, 2), 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) references customers(id)
);

create table products (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(255),
    price decimal(5, 2) NOT NULL,
    qty int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

create table product_orders (
    product_is int(11) NOT NULL,
    order_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    qty int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(product_id, order_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(product_id) references products(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(order_id) references orders(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

product_**is** int(11) NOT NULL, the correct one would be product_id, right?